# Icomoon.ttf is not loading

Tags: css

I am facing a problem with the icomoon fonts. I cannot load them at all.
But, if I hit for instance, this url:

localhost:8080/assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf (the project that im working on)

I can download the icomoon.ttf to my computer. If install them on my pc, everything is good. Icomoon font work. But this is not a solution.

How can I make it work? My relative paths seem correct

This is an example of my structure:

```
 index---
        |
      assets
          |_css
          |     |---icomoon.css
          |
          |_fonts
               |icomoon files
```

Here is my icomoon.css for you to see:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?cl02ar');
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?cl02ar#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?cl02ar') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?cl02ar') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?cl02ar#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-andr:before {
  content: "\e900";
}
.icon-arrow_b:before {
  content: "\e901";
}
.icon-fbeps:before {
  content: "\e902";
}
.icon-instagr:before {
  content: "\e903";
}
.icon-instagram_iconeps:before {
  content: "\e904";
}
.icon-map-markereps:before {
  content: "\e905";
}
.icon-mc:before {
  content: "\e906";
}
.icon-plus_b:before {
  content: "\e907";
}
.icon-plus:before {
  content: "\e908";
}
.icon-radio_icon:before {
  content: "\e909";
}
.icon-search_icon:before {
  content: "\e90a";
}
.icon-tw_iconeps:before {
  content: "\e90b";
}
.icon-yteps:before {
  content: "\e90c";
}
.icon-map-markereps2:before {
  content: "\e90d";
}
.icon-close_btn:before {
  content: "\e90f";
}
.icon-plus_b2:before {
  content: "\e910";
}
.icon-plus2:before {
  content: "\e911";
}
.icon-top_arrow:before {
  content: "\e912";
}
.icon-video_play:before {
  content: "\e913";
}
.icon-arrow_c:before {
  content: "\e914";
}
.icon-burger:before {
  content: "\e915";
}
.icon-minus:before {
  content: "\e90e";
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What web server? Will need to add mime types if you are on IIS.

Comment: I'm on apache. (using MAMP)

Comment: I would use developer inspector to see what error code you get from attempting to load the font file in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Should that really be relative from the css directory?

Should the path not be from Apache base path?

```
src: url('assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?cl02ar');
```